# Micronaut: How to create queues in ChannelPoolListener when multiple connections exist

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-rabbitmq

Micronaut 3.0.2 with `io.micronaut.rabbitmq:micronaut-rabbitmq` dependency.

I would like to use multiple connections and then use the proposed `ChannelPoolListener` based on `io.micronaut.rabbitmq.connect.ChannelInitializer` to create queues/exchanges using a specific connection named `configbus`.

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronautRabbitmq
rabbitmq:
  servers:
    configbus:
      uri: amqp://localhost:5672
      username: micronautRabbitmq
      password: micronautRabbitmq
    eventbus:
      uri: amqp://localhost:5671
      username: micronautRabbitmq
      password: micronautRabbitmq
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `micronaut-rabbitmq:3.1.0` the ChannelInitializer gets the name of the connection. So, whenever the initialize method is called for the desired connection, you can use the channel to create queues, exchanges, bindings, etc.

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-rabbitmq/latest/guide/#initialization

Answer (score 0):

You might be just missing the host and port keys there.

See the connections section here:
https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-rabbitmq/latest/guide/#config

Comment: See the `uri` attribute. It combines host and port.